# Meaning of numbers at the end of config files in Apache2 settings dump

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

By

```
apache2ctl -S
```

I have something like that:

```
...
port 80 namevhost host1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/host1.com.config:3)
port 80 namevhost host2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/host2.com.config:5)
...
```

What does numbers after config files paths mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line number in the configuration file where the `<VirtualHost>` directive begins that corresponds to the particular virtual host.

Apache retrieves its vhost settings using  the `DUMP_VHOSTS` parameter option available to the httpd binary.